# remote object Url

Tags: c#, webserver, remoteobject

Someone know waht this address means ? i know that is somthing with remote object

tcp://cikpfdb.cik.ff.com:8095/DataLoaderRemoteObject

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it means the a tcp service is hosted on a cikpfdb.cik.ff.com server running on port 8095 with name DataLoaderRemoteObject

Answer (score 0):

It's a generic TCP/IP connection to host **cikpfdb.cik.ff.com** on port **8095** (no specific protocol)